# Modify all elements into unknown type of list

Tags: java, list, iterator, updates

How Modify all elements into unknown type of list?

```
for (Person person : persons) {
            person = transformer.transform(person);
        }
```

But this construction create new person every time, I know that it's wrong. And I guess that it's better to use iterator but, I don't know how should I do  it exactly. Please don't give me any links to javadoc iterator.
Ok If it was ArrayList I just need to do like this

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < persons.size ; i++) {
                persons[i] = transformer.transform(persons[i]);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean an unknown type of list? You already know that the list is a `List` of `Person`. And what are the modifications you want to do?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "unknown type of list"? And what does your "this construction create new person every time" mean? Please take a bit of time to give more context into what you're trying to achieve, ideally with a short but complete program.

Comment: I mean that I know only List<Person>, but I do not know on what it based. It mabe ArrayList or any other

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. What exactly do you want to do with this Collection of Person?

Comment: You don't have to know what type of List it is for this to work which is the beauty of using a List interface and not a concrete List type. Your question remains unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily replace the transformed instance of a `Person` by using the method [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) of interface `List` (that means every `List` implementation like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` supports that):

```
for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    final Person person = persons.get(i);
    persons.set(i, transformer.transform(person)); // replace new instance of "Person"
    // do other stuff with "person"
}
```

Mind that the usage of `set` is only necessary if the method `transform` returns a new instance of `Person`. If it just modifies the provided instance, then you just need to iterate over your list:

```
for (Person person : persons) {
    transformer.transform(person); //just modify the current "Person" instance
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, you can't redefine the elements of the Java for (object obj : objects) loop. Unless transform() alters a property of the Person object, you'll have to iterate through using the other for construction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    // use persons.set() here to reassign the index in persons
}
```

Also, you typically don't need to know exactly what kind of `List` you're getting. The idea behind interfaces like List is that every object that implements it can be used where List is called for. Each of their properties and methods are a superset of those within the List interface.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use guava?

```
Collections2.transform(collection, new Function<Person, Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person apply(Person person) {
            return transformer.transform(person);
        }
});
```

But it would be probably better just to modify current Person instance.